# Update values in one column in same table to another in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Am trying to update my 1 table with new id's based on below scenario
[image]

in each step the `new_ID` column gets updated if it was previously used as can be seen in step 2, 3,4. The table can hold a small set of records or millions. Trying to determine best approach with sql server.

My approach is with a stored proc with 2 update statements

```
update old_new set newid = @newValue where oldid = @OldValue
update old_new set newid = @newValue  where newid = @OldValue
```

This looks like a performance nightmare waiting to happen. Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: What would this be a "performance nightmare"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you're concern about performance, you can combine both update into one :

```
update old_new set newid = @newValue where oldId = @OldValue or newid = @OldValue
```